# how to use Foreign key in L2E or EF?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `User` table which has a `PrivilegeId` foreign key points to a `Privilege` table and is the primary key there.

In Entity Framework, the VS will not generate a `PrivilegeId` variable under `User` for you. It will generate a `Privilege` property and `PrivilegeReference` property for you instead.

When I load a `User`, the `Privilege` property is `null` by default. That means EF does not load refered entity for you automatically. I think I may did something wrong? I cannot load `Privilege` separatedly because I have no info about the `Privilege` at that time. I guess EF should load the refered entities for me but I missed something. I need the `PrivilegeId` associated with my `User` object.

anybody can help me?

```
EDIT:
```

another answer: [What are Navigation Properties in Entity Framework for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262307/what-are-navigation-properties-in-entity-framework-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [Include method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).

```
List<User> users = context.Users.Include("Privilege").ToList();
```

Comment: is there a way to get the table name programmatically instead of hard code the table name?

Comment: The method accepts a string, and it's easy to programmatically supply a string.

Comment: If instead you want a compiler-checked technique be used instead of a compiler-opaque string, here's a link. http://blogs.msdn.com/stuartleeks/archive/2008/08/27/improving-objectquery-t-include.aspx