# how to use Foreign key in L2E or EF when needs insert?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I know during the retrieve, I can use Include() to load related Entities ([how to use Foreign key in L2E or EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632323/how-to-use-foreign-key-in-l2e-or-ef)). but when I want to save or insert data, how to handle those reference Entities?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480872/entity-framework-setting-a-foreign-key-property

Answer (score 1):

You need to hang the object within its graph, and call save changes.  ObjectContext takes care of the rest.

```
Customer customer = myObjectContext.Single(c => c.Name == "Bob");

//new up an Order instance that has never been in the database.
Order order = GetOrderForCar();

//Add order to the Orders ObjectSet of a Customer
// This connects order to our ObjectContext.
customer.Orders.Add(order);

myObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```